# How to convert 1min OHLC data into 5min OHLC data

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to convert 1 minute OHLC (Open/High/Low/Close) data into 5 minute OHLC data in Excel 2013. So far I know the principle. `Open` has to take the open value every 5 rows, similarly for `Close`. `Min`/`Max` is also understandable. Unfortunately Excel can't understand that I want to get `Min`/`Max` from rows 0-5, 5-10 etc. it goes 0-5, 1-6, 2-7 etc.

I was also trying to use AVERAGE somehow but it's pointless since its output doesn't correspond with reality at all. From some more research I think I will have to create a macro from functions AVERAGE, OFFSET, INDEX and MATCH and that's where my struggle begins. I have no idea how to construct that formula.

Here's a picture of how it looks after using Filter on the Count Column:

[image]

Comment: I will when I understand this SUBTOTAL thing. I got the A column and I understand the principe - number changes there every 5 rows i.e. 5 mins so I have the parts of data I need but now Im not sure where I should put this first SUBTOTAL row. Is it row 2 cause thats the row where 0 changes first time? And I assume that I have to make another columns for this SUBTOTAL right? If its too complicated to describe, just post a little picture where A is 0 column, B is Time and C/D/E/F are Open, High, Low and Close columns so I can imagine better where exactly should I do this subtotal. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column (assumed to be A) on the left with `0` as a label and `=IF(MOD(B2,6)=0,1+A1,A1)` in A2 copied down. Subtotal for each change in `0` and use Count on all the other columns. Change the first subtotal row formulae to be:

ColumnC: `=C2`
ColumnD: `=SUBTOTAL(4,D2:D6)`
ColumnE: `=SUBTOTAL(5,E2:E6)`
ColumnF: `=F6`

Filter for ColumnA contains `c` and copy formulae down.

*Edit*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I finaly got the point and I almost have it. The problem I have after using Filter on Column where all the Counts are is that High/Low arent there. Open and Close seems to be alright, but instead of High/Low there are only 0 everywhere. Im not sure why. Im gonna give you props so I can hopefuly post an image of how it looks.

Comment: Ah sure I understand. But I found out another problem :(. I was controling the Counts just out of curiosity and I found out that some counts are long 10 rows instead of 6 or 3 instead of 6 etc. I think its because these data are from trading chart bars and in reality, some bars are missing cause in those 5 mins not a single trade was done. Here are two links on the data without this and with this problem: http://i.imgur.com/kN1mSJm.png   ;    http://i.imgur.com/EZxXnMk.png

Comment: I managed to fix the MOD formula, now its constant for every number but asi it starts, 0 lasts for first 5 rows and every other number till the end (1,2,3,4 ...) lasts for 6 rows. So Ive tried to change MOD into (B2,5) but there 0 lasts only for first 4 rows and every other number last for 5 rows. So it never goes like 0 = rows 1-5, 1 = rows 6-10, 2 = rows 11-15 etc. But its either 0 = rows 1-5, 1 = rows 6-11, 2 = rows 12-17 etc. when its MOD(B2,6) or 0 = rows 1-4, 1 = 5-9, 2 = rows 10-14 etc when its MOD(B2,5). If I can fix this, then SUBTOTAL and everything else should be ok I hope.

Comment: Done (nothing has happened if it was supposed to).

Comment: Yes this could be a way to go. Cause if rows are timed for example like this: 21, 22, 23, 25, 26 ... its not logical to take those 5 numbers since 26 doesnt even belong into 21-25 interval. I was already thinking about this way to go. Well it might be enough for separate question since I already know how to make this if I have all the data.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` library of Python would do it easily. Give it a try